# Ordering rows by repeating pattern

Tags: postgresql, order-by

Given a table in Postgres like

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  type text NOT NULL,
  value int NOT NULL
)
```

where `type` could be `A`, `B` or `C` and given an arbitrary, *repeating* pattern like

```
A B B C B B
```

how can I query the table so that the results are sorted first according to the pattern and then according to the value? In other words, the first row is the `A` with the lowest `value`, the second row is the `B` with the lowest `value`, the third row is the `B` with the second lowest `value` and so on. If we run out of particular type, we just move on to the next letter in the pattern (i.e. if we don't have any more `C`s to return, the pattern becomes `ABBBB`).

| type | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 8 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 9 |

The actual pattern is dynamic and has an arbitrary length, thought it will always be constrained to only the possible values for `type`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c50c) is a fiddle with sample data.

Comment: I have looked at this (+1 for an interesting question BTW) - but I would love to know what sort of practical application is the question's motivation - might be helpful for modelling it in my brain! I'll take a another look tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not easy with plain SQL, but still possible:

```
WITH pattern AS  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY ord) AS pos
   FROM   unnest('{A,B,B,C,B,B}'::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY t(type, ord)
              -- provide pattern here
   ) 
 , type_frequency AS (
   SELECT type, count(*) AS freq
   FROM   pattern
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT type, t.value -- , t.epoch, p.ord, pos
FROM  (
   SELECT type, value
        , ceil(rn / freq::float) AS epoch
        , (rn - 1) % freq + 1    AS pos
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY value) AS rn
      FROM   t1  -- base table here
      JOIN   type_frequency tf USING (type)
      ) sub
   ) t
JOIN   pattern p USING (type, pos)
ORDER  BY t.epoch, p.ord;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3005ea00bb0300d78e9aa6c163bcfe11)*

Produces exactly your desired result.

Would seem simpler with a procedural solution looping through the pattern and getting the next greater value per type from the table. But this query should still perform decently.

#### User instructions

Provide ***any*** pattern once in the first CTE `pattern`. Assuming base type `text`, but any type supporting equality works. Unnest using `WITH ORDINALITY` to preserve the original order of elements in the pattern (`ord`). Distill the position per type (`pos`) to match the same for table rows later. About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

The second CTE `type_frequency` computes distinct values and their respective frequency in the pattern.

In the outer query, in the subquery `sub`, join to `type_frequency` to filter only involved types while adding the frequency, and add a row number (`rn`) per type.

Dividing that `rn` by the value frequency `freq` produces an `epoch`, the principal order of rows. ([Can't use integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) here, that would truncate, so cast to `float`!)
`rn` [modulo (`%`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) `freq` produces the position `pos` per type. Shift back (`- 1`) and forth (`+ 1`) to fix an off-by-1 issue. We need an integer type for the modulo operation.

Finally, join to the pattern on `(type, pos)` to attach the original order (`ord`) in the pattern per `epoch`.